# what is the difference between top.Ext.getCmp() and Ext.getCmp() in extjs

Tags: extjs

I'am New To Extjs.In a Program I'am See top.Ext.getCmp() and Ext.getCmp() used.I Can't

understand what is the diffrence between them.Pls Help Me Anyone.

Comment: Yeah, I also think it has something to do with moving in DOM. My suggestion is that `top` refers to the parent of the component, but why don't you try `console.log` using the both expressions for the same component and try to get the answer yourself by inspecting the results.

Answer (score 2):

From the MDN:

> Returns a reference to the topmost window in the window hierarchy.

This is commonly used when trying to refer to something in a parent frame inside an iframe.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top